# CNAME getting redirected to /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, cname

I have a website on cPanel say located on **domain1.com**. It has a subdomain as **subdomain1.domain1.com** and is accessible through browser.

But when I create a CNAME (**subdomain2.domain2.com** pointing to **subdomain1.domain1.com**), it goes to http://subdomain2.domain2.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Not sure where or what I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: subdomain2.domain2.com it's added to Cpanel account ? If subdomain2.domain2.com it's not on Apache, not work and send your petition to defaultwebpage.cgi.

Comment: subdomain2.domain2.com is on another server which wants to fetch data from subdomain1.domain1.com. CNAME is created from subdomain2.domain2.com to point to subdomain1.domain1.com.

Comment: Also  if I create a CNAME from cPanel server to outside account it works fine, but when I create a CNAME on cPanel to point to another subdomain on cPanel, then the same error accours

Comment: If subdomain2.domain2.com go to subdomain2.domain2.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi ot's because CNAME not point to subdomain1.domain1.com. Point to subdomain2.domain2.com. check wuth dig +short subdomain2.domain2.com